# Good place to learn about every option/button in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: video, after-effects

In particular, right now anyway, I want to know what the following under Animation menu do:

- Track Camera
- Track in mocha AE
- Warp Stabilizer
- Track Motion

Looking for a text-based explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User Guide has all this information.

Online, visit the [Adobe After Effects Help pages here](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/topics.html) and read the Animation and Keyframes section. As an example, the Track Camera page says:

> **3D camera tracker effect**
>
> The 3D camera tracker effect analyzes video sequences to extract
>   camera motion and 3D scene data. The 3D camera motion allows you to
>   correctly composite 3D elements over your 2D footage.